# Comic with disturbing imagery

Tags: story-identification, comics

I recall reading a comic book (possibly a graphic novel) in the late 80's which had some disturbing imagery.  I can't recall much but here are some of the things I do remember;

- A very burly reformed criminal (possibly forcibly reformed?) donates his own arm to a child.  It was comic (pun intended) how out of place the child looked with one big burly arm, but he/she loved the man for donating it.
- A different child with a bandaged head is all dopey (possibly drugged) while an evil dude manically eats part of his/her body

The comic was from my cousin's collection, so I didn't get more than a brief look at it and now it is 30+ years old, so I am not holding out much hope.  However, every now and then these images come to mind and I wonder what the original comic was.

Thanks!

EDIT: Adding some additional details. 
The burly guy was definitely an antagonist earlier in the comic.  Later, I think he realises he was duped and is angry he gave away his arm.

Comment: These both sound like *Heavy Metal*, but I don't recognize the individual stories.

Comment: It's not from the first 30 issues or so of *Heavy Metal*, nor from the similar *Epic Comic*. I would have remembered that. Maybe it is from UK comics *2000 AD* or *Warrior* - some of their stories were quite grizzly.

Comment: @ZeissIkon Perhaps.  I don't have an easy way to find out, but thanks for the reply!

Comment: Not a comic, but that sounds like the Aeon Flux episode called "The Purge". https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0783304/?ref_=ttep_ep9

Comment: @Futoque I am pretty sure I read it, and the images were still images.  Unfortunately that link doesn't give me anything to go on.  Are there any portions of it I can view online?

Comment: @Trenin The only places I am seeing it online require some sort of subscription.  Some require cable/satellite logins to see.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

https://sadgeezer.com/aeon-flux-long-episodes-the-purge-2/

This answer is late.  I recently found a description of the episode mentioned in the comments.  Here is a synopsis of the episode with some images.  The description in the question immediately made me think of the image attached here.

There is a scene in the episode where a person taken over by a mechanical endoskeleton serves a woman food from a tray off the top of his head.  There is also a scene at a food station where everyone eats cabbages thinking they are getting personalized meals.  The voiceover on the scene sounds like someone chanting twisted nursery rhymes and they eat robotically.  The angle makes it look like they are eating brains.

This isn't a printed story, but the plot elements are similar.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!   This answer is _not_ late, it's arrived at the proper time. :)  Any good answer is always timely.  It's possible there was a printed version of the story, and this might help find it.

Comment: @Futoque Thanks!  I think this is right for the boy and the arm.  I might be getting the other part mixed up.